# What makes a vector an object with both magnitude and direction?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

According to my understanding, A vector is an element of a set called the vector space which satisfies a list of axioms like : closure under vector addition, closure under scalar multiplication, associativity, commutativity, distributivity, the existence of : a zero vector(additive identity), multiplicative identity , additive inverse and so on.

They're quite useful in physics for at least two reasons:

1)a vector is a quantity that has both magnitude and direction, and such a quantity pops up a lot in physics.

2)a vector is invariant under co-ordinate rotation and translation. Now this is pretty important because: if a physical law can be described by vector equation (e.g. Newton's second law) then this law is invariant under co-ordinate rotation and translation, a property that every physical law should satisfy.

My question is : How does an element in vector space(i.e. a vector) which satisfies the aforementioned list of axioms imply that this element(this vector) is a quantity that has both magnitude and direction?

In addition to that, How does satisfying the aforementioned axioms make this element(this vector) invariant under rotation and translation of coordinates?

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted, it really is a very good question. I think that if students asked questions like this more often, they would get through their studies quicker.

Comment: I think you're conflating two different definitions of "vector": the physicist's definition, and the mathematician's definition. The vector space axioms constitute the mathematician's definition. In order to get a "physical vector", you need to add additional structure on top of that: the ability to calculate a norm, and the behavior under rotation and translation.

Comment: You are talking about a http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Normed_space and not all vectors have a "direction" to speak of. See http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Basis_and_coordinates for a discussion on that (well worth reading)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Elements of a real vectorspace certainly have direction, but they don't really have a magnitude. Well actually, they... *kind-of* have a magnitude. But for a proper magnitude, you need further structure, such as a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) or [inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html). Let me explain.

**Vector Spaces.**

Suppose $V$ is a real vectorspace.

> **Definition 0.** Given a vectors $x,y \in V$, we say that $x$ and $y$
>   *have the same direction* iff:
>
> - there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $x = ry,$ and
> - there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $y = rx$.
>
> (The $r$'s don't have to be the same.)

This induces an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) on $V$, so we get a partitioning of $V$ into cells. Each cell is an open ray, so long as we regard $\{0\}$ as an open ray. You may wish to exclude $\{0\}$ from its privileged position as a ray, in which case you should only deal with non-zero vectors; that is, you need to be dealing with $V \setminus \{0\}$ rather than $V$.

Irrespective of which conventions are used, we can make sense of direction using these ideas:

> **Definition 1.** The **direction** of $x \in V$ is the unique open ray $R \subseteq V$ such that $x \in R$.

Notice that the equivalence relation of having the same direction is preserved under scalar multiplication; what I mean is that if $v$ and $w$ have the same direction, then $av$ and $aw$ have the same direction, for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Geometrically, this means that if we scale a ray, we'll end up with a subset of another ray.

As for magnitude; well, if you choose a ray $R \subseteq V$, then we can partially order $R$ as follows. Given $x,y \in R$, we define that $x \geq y$ iff $x = ry$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$. So some vectors along this ray are longer than others, hence magnitude.

**Inner Product Spaces.**

Actually, this isn't the whole story. The problem with vector spaces is that if $x$ and $y$ don't belong to the same ray (nor to the the "negatives" of each others rays), then there's no way of comparing the magnitudes of $x$ and $y$. We can't say which is longer! Now there are mathematical situations where this limitation is desirable, but physically, you probably don't want this. A related issue is that you can't really make sense of angles in a (mere) vector space; at least, not without some further structure.

For this reason, when physicists say "vector", what they usually mean is "element of a finite-dimensional [inner-product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)." This is a (finite-dimensional) vector space $V$ with further structure; in particular, it comes equipped with a function

$$\langle-,-\rangle : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

that is required to satisfy certain axioms resembling the dot product. Especially important for us is that these axioms include a "non-negativity" condition:

$$\langle x,x\rangle \geq 0$$

Using this, we can define the magnitude of vectors as follows.

> **Definition 2.** Suppose $V$ is a real inner product space. Then the *norm* (or "magnitude") of $x \in V$, denoted $\|x\|$, is defined a follows:
>
> $$\|x\| = \langle x,x\rangle^{1/2}$$

This allows us to compare the magnitudes of vectors that don't live in the same ray; we simply define that $x \geq y$ means $\|x\| \geq \|y\|.$ When confined to a single ray, this agrees with our earlier definition! Be careful though, because the relation $\geq$ we just defined is only a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder).

In fact, the inner product gives us more than just magnitudes; it also gives angles!

> **Definition 3.** Suppose $V$ is a real inner product space. Then the *angle between* of $x,y \in V$, denoted $\mathrm{ang}(x,y)$, is defined a follows:
>
> $$\mathrm{ang}(x,y) = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}\right)$$

It can be shown that vectors $x$ and $y$ have the same direction (in the sense described at the beginning of my post) iff the angle between them is $0$. In fact, you can modify the above definition so that it defines the angle between any two **non-zero open rays**. In this case, it turns out that two rays are equal iff the angle between them is $0$.

Comment: Very nice and informative answer.

Comment: @JonathanHebert, thanks! I'm rather proud of it :)

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer!

Comment: @goblin Can you elaborate on the fact that, such element of finite dimensional inner-product space (that is, the vector in the sense used in physics) is invariant under coordinate rotation and translation?

Comment: @OmarNagib, thanks for the kind words. Unfortunately I don't know much physics, so I can't really help you there, but I'll let you know 
if anything shows up. Also, I've had a bit of a snoop around wikipedia, and the whole issue of invariance in physics really isn't dealt with in a mathematically precise way anywhere that I can see. I think its probably quite an advanced concept.

Comment: @OmarNagib, quoting from wikipedia: "Gauge theories are usually discussed in the language of differential geometry. Mathematically, a gauge is just a choice of a (local) section of some principal bundle. A gauge transformation is just a transformation between two such sections." So it sounds like you need some pretty serious differential geometry to even make sense of invariance in physics.

Comment: @goblin My follow up question is purely mathematical, to reformulate it:
it seems to me that the inner product function which defines the norm and the direction of a vector is coordinate independent, is this the case? and if so, can you elaborate more on How it is ?

Comment: @OmarNagib, oh sure, sorry I misread your comment.

Comment: @OmarNagib, it will take me a while to write something, perhaps a few days, since translation-invariance pertains to [affine spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space), which I'm much less familiar with.

Comment: @goblin Work at your own pace.

Answer (score 1):

The word "vector" is used to mean different things in math.  Sometimes "vector" means "an ordered $n$-tuple of real numbers".  Sometimes it means an equivalence class of directed line segments (with respect to a certain equivalence relation).  Sometimes it means an element of a particular vector space.  Which definition is being used depends on context.  If a vector space does not have a norm defined on it, then indeed the elements of that vector space do not have magnitudes.  In that context the "magnitude" of a vector has not been defined.

Comment: Although my knowledge of linear algebra is pretty archaic, it seems to me, that the "different" definitions you provided for vectors are not so different. you said a vector is maybe 1)  a $n$-tuple of real numbers  2) an element of vector space and 3) a directed line segment. How these definitions are different? they seem to me to describe exactly the same object.

Comment: Btw I said an *equivalence class* of directed line segments, not a directed line segment.  That's an important distinction.  You commonly encounter vector spaces whose elements are not ordered $n$-tuples of real numbers, and yet the elements of such a vector space are still called "vectors" in that context.